# how to print a specific area of a web page in c sharp

Tags: asp.net

hey guys, m building a web-page in that theres a

tag which holds some documentary data, so i want to print that specific data and not the whole page i.e banner, textfeilds etc... since i know window.print() function prints the whole page, but how to print a sepicific area in a page.

Comment: please check my answer, it includes how we can print specific part(s) of webpage, also it includes css and javascript requirements which makes it flexible. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print a specific area of a page, but you can hide the rest of the page when printing. Create a CSS that hides the element that you don't want to print:

```
@media print {
  .someelement, .otherelement, .morelement { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: i have a problem coz i have my page as nested table and i want to print a table which is nested inside other.. so if m hiding the outermost table then how can i print the inside one.

Comment: @FosterZ: You can't, so you have to find some other way of specifying what you want to hide. With your current layout you would have to hide the cells separately so that you can single out the one you want printed.

Comment: ok thanks, better i re-structure my page so that i can use this @media..1 more thing, when m printing the page images like banner,logo r not printing only text is get printed..thr r some gif images in my table that i want to print too..

Comment: @FosterZ: By default (at least in IE) background images and colors are not printed, but that can be enabled by the user. If you use image tags instead, they should always be printed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a print style sheet, which sets the `display` property on everything except what you want printed to `none`.

You can load different stylesheets for different media using the `media` attribute.

style.css:

```
#header 
{
    background-color: #ccc;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 4em;
    clear: both;
}
```

print.css:

```
#header
{
    display: none;
}
```

yourpage.aspx:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">My Site!</div>
    <div id="content">
      Only print me
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can print specific part(s) of webpage.

It also includes how to implement css and javascript in the printout page.

Also for multiple part of pages, you can apply "< br >" tag as I implemented below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printCommission() {
    // For logo html (part 1 for print out)
    var prtContent = document.getElementById("logo");

    // This is the div I was required to include in print out (part 2 for print out)    
    var prtContent1 = document.getElementById("dashboardbody1");

    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    // To apply css  
    WinPrint.document.write("<style> .commission td, .commission th {border-color: #CCCCCC;padding: 4px;}  .commission th {background-color: #106C9B;border-color: #CCCCCC;color: #FFFFFF;} .commission { border-collapse: collapse; color: #000000; text-align: center; } .commission td.td-noborder { border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;} .bg-grey {    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CCCCCC;} .bold {    font-weight: bold !important;}</style>");

    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML + "<br><br>" + prtContent1.innerHTML);

    // to apply javascript (I used it to hide buttons) 
    WinPrint.document.write("<script type='text/javascript'>" + " window.onload=function(){ document.getElementById('downloadReport').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('printout').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('imgCommission').style.display='none';}; <" + "/" + "script>");

    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
    return false;
```

}